# What is best practice for dealing with blank ('') string values on non-nullable model fields?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

In Django/postgres if you have a non-nullable field, it's still possible to store a blank `str` value `''` for certain field types (e.g. `CharField`, `TextField`).

Note I am not referring to `blank=False`, which simply determines if the field is rendered with `required` in a modelForm. I mean a literal blank string value.

For example, consider this simple model that has `null=False` on a `CharField`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', null=False)
```

The following throws an `IntegrityError`:

```
MyModel.objects.create(title=None)
```

Whilst the following does not, and creates the object:

```
MyModel.objects.create(title='')
```

Is this an unintended consequence of combining postgres with Django, or is it intended / what practical uses does it have?

If it's unintended, what's best practice to deal with this? Should every `CharField` and `TextField` with `null=False` also have a `CheckConstraint`? E.g.

```
Class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=~models.Q(title=''),
            name='title_required'
        )
    ]
```

Comment: If `null=False`, then you can not add a `Null`/`None`, this is rejected by the database. Most databases will check for null. Empty strings are however not `NULL`, an empty string is normally not constrained by the type.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, yes that's what I understood. What I don't follow is what's the use case for an empty string in a database? Logically I would use `null=False` if I want to ensure a value, which an empty string does not? Is best practice to enforce this with a `CheckConstraint` or am I missing something?

Comment: `NULL` should signify "I don't know."  An empty string, `''` signifies "I know what it is; it is empty."  Please see and accept the answer @AdrianKlaver left and take his last paragraph to heart.  Django is wrong just as Oracle was wrong thirty years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null

"Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL. "

This is because there is common misconception out there that '' = NULL and Django decided to go with that. I personally think it was a bad decision but there it is.  A string of length 0 is still a value as is an integer = 0.

Comment: So basically if you want to enforce a `Charfield` that is not blank at the database level, you have to use a `CheckConstraint` on `value=''`...?

Comment: Yes, as '' is an otherwise valid value.

Comment: I just manually set the Charfield(default=None) so that if its nullable it will be set as NULL instead of empty string, or if non-nullable, will raise IntegrityError on DB level